# cant use scriptManager RegisterClientScriptBlock witgh AJAX AsyncFileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

Using a 'ajaxToolKit:AsyncFileUpload" to upload images to my application:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload OnClientUploadError="uploadError"
                                OnClientUploadComplete="ajaxUploadImage_ClientUploadComplete" runat="server"
                                ID="ajaxUploadImage" Width="400px" UploaderStyle="Modern"
                                CompleteBackColor = "White"
                                UploadingBackColor="#CCFFFF"  ThrobberID="imgLoader"
                                OnUploadedComplete = "ajaxUploadImage_OnUploadComplete" 
                                 OnClientUploadStarted="AssemblyFileUpload_Started" 
                              />
```

the problem being I want to add a limit to the amount of images a user can upload, if the limit is succeed fire a 'attachmentLimitReachedScript' popUp from scriptManager, if not continue...but am i correct in saying you cant use a script manager from inside an ajax control...any ideas of a work around?

```
protected void ajaxUploadImage_OnUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            //attachment limit has not been reached, DO NOT UPLOAD IMAGES 
            if (hasUserReachedImageUploadLimit())
            {
                return;
            }

            //attachment limit has not been reached, continue with other functionality
}

    protected bool hasUserReachedImageUploadLimit()
        {
            bool limitReached = false; 

            DataAccess.Classes.CheckPricePlan CheckCustomerAccountLimitations = new DataAccess.Classes.CheckPricePlan();
            string attachmentLimitReachedScript = CheckCustomerAccountLimitations.imageTableSize(currentUser.UserWorkspace.WorkSpaceID, currentUser.UserWorkspace.Organisation.ID);
            //if attachmentLimitReachedScript !=  "AllowedToImage", attachment limit has been reached, display popUp
            if (attachmentLimitReachedScript != "AllowedToAddAttachment")
            {
                attachmentLimitReachedScript += "(alert('end'));";
                string test = "(alert('start'));" + attachmentLimitReachedScript;
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(upViewUploadImages, upViewUploadImages.GetType(), "attachmentLimitReachedScript", test, true);
                upViewUploadImages.Update();
                limitReached = true;
            }

            return limitReached;
        }
```

I have added an alert(start) and alert(end) before and after the script. both alerts are showing and I know the script isnt the problem because I am calling it elsewhere on the same page and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is no option to limit number of uploading files.

You can hide or break in any way the control with client code when `OnClientUploadComplete` event occurs.

Or you can set `Visible=false`, so server-side `OnPreRender()` method will not be called and control will not react to sending files.